# Can I use a Select Query (MS Access Database) to get values between two non null values?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a table which contains values and nulls.

I want to select all the values that come between two non null characters.
In the PO column there is a value followed by some nulls and then a different value.

Is there a way I can select the 'Sample Values' between '123' and '456'?

```
|  Sample Value  |  PO  |
------------------------
|1               | 123  |
|2               | null |
|3               | null |
|4               | null |
|5               | 456  |
```

The PO no. will be user input so I want to keep getting values until a non null PO no. comes up again. I won't know the second PO and the no. of entries between two PO's is variable so I can't use `SELECT TOP n`

Thanks

EDIT:

I also have the primary key field which auto increments

Comment: The notion of "between" in this case does not apply - you dont know how they are stored.  select the rows where PO IS NULL

Comment: This could be solved using code and an OleDbDataReader. It is mandatory to use a query? Did you expect to have many values between the two limits?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the below query is what you're looking for. When you run this query the field [Enter First Value] will pop up with an input box when you run the query. When I enter '123', I get the results you're looking for. Now, if this isn't what you're looking for with respect to your real data, you may need to refine the question. For example, I'm assuming that the [Sample Value] field has a unique constraint which may or may not be true.

Edited to only require first PO#

```
SELECT [Sample Value]
FROM Table1
WHERE [Sample Value] > (
    SELECT [Sample Value] 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE PO = [Enter PO]
    ) 
AND [Sample Value] < (
    SELECT Min([Sample Value])
    FROM Table1
    WHERE PO is not null 
    AND [Sample Value] >
    (
        SELECT [Sample Value] 
        FROM Table1
        WHERE PO = [Enter PO]
    )
```

Comment: I won't know the second PO, I can only get the first one from the user and I have to read sample values from the first PO to the second PO. I also have a primary key field which I can use.

Comment: Tweaked it to only ask for one PO#. Still not sure if this will totally satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try...

```
select st.sampleValue
from sampleTable st
left join sampleTable st2
on st2.po=st.po
where 
st.PO=123 or
(st.pk > st2.pk &&
st.pk <
(select top 1 st3.pk
from sampleTable st3
where st3.pk > st2.pk
&& st3.po is not null
order by st3.pk asc))
order by st.sampleValue asc
```